# What is "@c.us" means in whatsapp-web.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, whatsapp

Is there any reference or resources about "@c.us" that i can refer to?

example as below:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log('Client is ready!');

  // Your message.
 const text = "Hey john";

  // Getting chatId from the number.
  // we have to delete "+" from the beginning and add "@c.us" at the end of the number.
 const chatId = "911234567890@c.us";

 // Sending message.
 client.sendMessage(chatId, text);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Not aware of such doc (if there is one - I'll update this answer), but in general:

```
<number>@c.us -- the <number> is user id
<number>@g.us -- the <number> is group id
```

> Got the info from here https://chat-api.com/en/docs.html

Comment: @syahid246 you are rite! fixed